# Form errros are not visible

Tags: angular

I can't figure out why my form.errors are not visible in app.component.html (line 40). 
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1vdyu9)

Comment: because you have not set any error message there in the code

Comment: You're mixing template and reactive forms there. Put the validators to the FormGroup directly.

Comment: how can i set error message in login-form-row component?

Comment: @JohnB you can write custom validator and check form control base on required or value and return an object or null if everything is valid log for custom validator for form group

Answer (score 0):

Form error will be an errors related to validation that add for the form it self it not not related to form controls normally these validation methods are custom method like in password forms check if new password and confirm password are values equals

> from doc [errors](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#errors) An object containing any errors generated by failing
>   validation, or null if there are no errors.

you can display error message for any control like this

```
 <div *ngIf="form.get('firstName').hasError('required') && form.get('firstName').touched ">
   required 
 </div>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53612894)